# Prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k(k+1)\binom{n}{k}=0$

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k(k+1)\binom{n}{k}=0$.

I know $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}=0$ and even $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\dfrac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}=0$ because I can multiply left side by n+1 and divided by n+1. 
Then I have $\dfrac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\dfrac{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\dfrac{-1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}=0$.

Now, how do I eliminate the term (k+1) in the equation $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k(k+1)\binom{n}{k}=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $$x(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}x^{k+1}$$

Differentiate and evaluate at $x=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$k$th term$\displaystyle=T_k=(k+1)\binom nk=k\binom nk+\binom nk$

$\displaystyle=k\frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!}+\binom nk =k\frac{n\cdot(n-1)!}{k\cdot(k-1)!\{(n-1)-(k-1)\}!}+\binom nk$

$\displaystyle\implies T_k=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom nk$

Put $k=0,1,2,\cdots,n-1,n$ and add to get $$\sum_{0\le k\le n}(-1)^k(k+1)\binom nk=-n(1-1)^{n-1}+(1-1)^n$$